# Checking if *char is whitespace or characters C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, strtok

I was trying to discard invalid values, i.e. `whitespaces` and `characters` as I want to only parse double values.

My `.txt` file looks like this...

```
1.45-1.46
    -1.56
1.78-dead
-abc
1.34-2.45
1.56-9.01
```

Basically, I only want to store valid doubles, so the first line `1.45-1.46`, the fifth line `1.34-2.45` and the last line `1.56-9.01` are valid and the rest are invalid.

I have written some code, however it does not recognize the `whitespace` or `characters`.  I am getting a `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer` error.

This is the code

```
  char **marks;
  marks = new char*[7]
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
  {
    marks[i] = new char[64];
    istreams.getline(marks[i], 64);
    char *delims;
    delims = strtok (marks[i]," -");
    while (delims != NULL)
    {
      if(delims == '') // DOES NOT LIKE THIS, I WANT IT TO CHECK FOR WHITESPACE AND ALPHA CHARACTERS LIKE 'A', 'B', 'C'...
      {
         cout << "Invalid double" << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << atof(delims);
        delims = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are using `new` and `cout`, so this is not C. But why not use `std::string`?

Comment: Hint: `delims` is a *pointer* to a character.

Comment: This code performs no input extraction *at all*. You allocate `marks` as `new char[64]`, then send that indeterminate data buffer content straight to `strtok`, and thusly invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @WhozCraig, `marks` array has data now.

Comment: What should `''` be in `== ''` ? My compiler does not accept an empty character constant.

Comment: @MartinR even if you do specify a character, your compiler won't really enjoy comparing a `char*` against a `char`

Comment: @SamThers I think you need to review how `strtok` *works*. It (a) skips all delimiters at the beginning of the input text, then sets a start pointer, skips all characters *NOT* in the delimiter set until it encounters either EOS or something in the delimiter set. If the latter, it *replaces* the discovered delimiter with a null char and returns the start-pointer. See [**`std::strtok`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok), but honestly I don't think it is the correct function for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm amazed at how many `marks` questions there have been in the past week. Assignment due soon? Is your instructor forcing all of you to use char arrays rather than std::string?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the functions

```
isalpha(int)
isspace(int)
```

You'll need to check each char individually by casting it to an int, though:

```
bool containsWhitespace(char const * c) {
    char temp = *c;
    if(temp != '\0') {
        if( isspace(temp) )
           return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return containsWhitespace(++c);
}

int main() {
    if(containsWhitespace("ThisIsATest")) printf("First test failed.");
    if(!containsWhitespace("This is a test")) printf("Second test failed.");
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Comment: If I remember correctly, isalpha()/isspace() do *not* take a `char *` argument.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. It takes an int, which you can cast from a char. Updating answer.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: there is no "cast" in `isspace(temp)`, there is just an implicit conversion.  A cast is when you explicitly force an expression to convert to a different type.

Comment: You are technically correct. The best kind of correct. I had actually meant to explicitly cast it in my example, but then forgot. I won't update the answer to reflect this change, but @aschepler is right -- the compiler recognizes that it can make the conversion between char and int so it does it silently.

Comment: In fact, a `char` value should be (explicitly) converted to `unsigned char` before passing it to one of the `is_()` functions. Plain `char` is commonly signed, so a `char` value might be negative -- but `isspace()` has undefined behavior for a negative argument other than `EOF`. Replace `isspace(temp)` by `isspace((unsigned char)temp)`. (It's ugly that we have to do this, but we're stuck with it.)

Comment: Where are you getting "`isspace()` has undefined behavior for a negative argument other than EOF"? I don't see that in the docs for `isspace()`

Comment: I'd recommend [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) instead of cplusplus.com

Comment: Ah ha! I will bookmark this now. I've come across it via Google before, but this does seem to be a more complete reference. At the very least, it included the `unsigned` undefined behavior, which in my opinion is a glaring omission from the other.

Comment: @tigertrussell it is a considerably better reference. It is essentially a wiki maintained by some borderline-ocd language and library aficionados. It is also *screaming* fast.

Comment: @tigertrussell: If you want me to see a comment, tag it with my name. I see it in the [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the 2011 ISO C standard, section 7.1: "In all cases the argument is an **`int`**, the value of which shall be representable as an **`unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of the macro **`EOF`**. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."